# Unexpected result using LIMIT with CONSTRUCT

Tags: sparql

Something strange is going on in this `CONSTRUCT` query using `LIMIT`. I would expect to receive 1 or 2 solutions for `LIMIT 1` and `LIMIT 2`, respectively, i.e., one or two graphs, but instead I always get two graphs, with either 11 or 12 triples.

```
CONSTRUCT { 
  ex:sceneResource skos:related ?newSceneSubject.
  ?newSceneSubject a lcx:Scene ;
                   dcterms:subject ?type ; 
                   lcx:hasTitle ?title ;
                   lcx:describedBy ?thumbNail ;
                   lcx:motto ?motto ;
                   lcx:freebaseID ?freebaseID
}
WHERE { 
  { ?newSceneSubject a ex:interestType1 }
  UNION
  { ?newSceneSubject a ex:interestType2 } 
  ?newSceneSubject lcx:hasTitle ?title ;
                   a ?type .
                   lcx:freebaseID ?freebaseID .
  OPTIONAL { ?newSceneSubject lcx:motto ?motto  }
  OPTIONAL { ?newSceneSubject lcx:describedBy ?thumbNail }
}
LIMIT 2
```

Have I misunderstood `LIMIT` with `CONSTRUCT`, or is there a bug in the Jena API?

Answer (score 6):

Your question is a little unclear as to what you were expecting and what you actually got but I will attempt to answer anyway.

The `LIMIT` applies to the `WHERE` portion of a query, in the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#SolModandCONSTRUCT) there is an example of using `LIMIT` with `CONSTRUCT` and it states the following:

> the output graph from the CONSTRUCT template is formed from just two
>   of the solutions from graph pattern matching

i.e. it takes *at most* two rows from the `WHERE` clause and feeds them to the `CONSTRUCT` template.

Since the template can generate potentially many triples the actual maximum number of results is the limit multiplied by the number of triple patterns in your template.  Since individual patterns in the template may generate invalid triples (and these are discarded per the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#construct)) the actual number of triples you get may be lower:

> If any such instantiation produces a triple containing an unbound
>   variable or an illegal RDF construct, such as a literal in subject or
>   predicate position, then that triple is not included in the output RDF
>   graph

So from what you've described and the specification Jena's behavior is perfectly correct.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I will clarify my concern. The query
 CONSTRUCT { <"+ m_sceneResource + "> skos:related ?newSceneSubject.  }  
 WHERE { {?newSceneSubject  rdf:type <" + interestType1 + ">} 
 UNION {?newSceneSubject  rdf:type <" + interestType2 +">}  
 UNION {?newSceneSubject  rdf:type <" + interestType3 +">}  .    
 " ?newSceneSubject rdf:type ?type. 
} LIMIT 3"

returns one, single triple graph and the same query with LIMIT 30 returns four, single triple graphs. I.e. there are at least 4 solutions to the WHERE portion, but only one  is returned when I put LIMIT 3.

Comment: @user2498899 That is completely unreadable, please use the edit button to edit your question and add that additional detail.  Also I don't understand what you mean by returning multiple graphs, a `CONSTRUCT` returns a single RDF graph so you should really explain that part of your question as well - preferably with expected vs actual results shown